# How can I make html submit button functional in flask?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, submit-button

I have a Flask application, and in my html template (which is Jinja2) I have a simple form which has only a button:

```
<form name='resetLayoutForm' method='POST'>
    <input type="submit" value="Reset layout" class="submitButton"/> 
</form>
```

Now, I want to know how can I 'let the Python script know' that the button was clicked?

I tried with:

```
@app.route('/localhost/some_route', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def function():
    .   .    .
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # code
    .   .    .
```

but this isn't a good solution, because I have some other operations in the code that are using the POST request method, and I don't want #code to be activated when I use these other POST operations.

Comment: so make the button post to a different handler that only responses to that button?

Comment: just duplicate the form that contains the button and set it's action to a different URL.

Comment: That won't be good for my purpose. I want the code to be executed on the same URL.

Comment: So simply include a token in the button form that tells "other code" not to execute when you press that button and to execute when you use the "right" POST operation. You are making this more complex then it needs to be I think.

Comment: You want to execute using the same form, same action URL, on the server. Then what is the need to execute this "other python script" separately. I don't get it it. Why can't you just execute the python script and continue with rest of whatever u need to do using the same POST.

Comment: @PaulC, I did it like you said after all: "just duplicate the form that contains the button and set it's action to a different URL". It seems to be much more simpler this way. Thanks for the comment! Write it as an answer if you want, so I can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate the form that contains the button and set it's action to a different URL. Then, when pressed, only that different URL will receive the data.

Obviously, as others have noted, there are Javascript mechanisms to achieve this but if those are not needed...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "'let the Python script know' that the button was clicked?"

If you don't want to talk to the server and the button click is only for client side, then why not use Javascript ? For example, the simplest way would be to use the onclick event :

```
<input type="submit" value="Reset layout" class="submitButton" onclick=doSomething() />
```

where doSomething() is a javascript function you can write

Comment: I mean, when you click the button, to send POST request to the python script and execute some Python code. The answer you suggested will not satisfy my needs, because doSomething() needs to be a Python script, not JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do (of course, after the button is clicked)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the input's value attribute with `request.form.values()` as such:

```
@app.route('/localhost/some_route', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def function():
    # code
    if 'Reset_layout' in request.form.values():
        # code
```